# Windows 10 Asks me to Enter a Password

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows 10 Pro x64 on my personal laptop on which I have a single user account with no password. For some reason however, Windows 10 has started asking me to enter a password whenever I boot up my machine. All I have to do is press the button without entering anything, and I log in, but I would much rather skip this step in favor of an automatic sign-in. Why has this started happening only now? What can I do to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how to stop the computer from asking for a password every time:

1. Right-click the Windows Logo (Start Button) and click "Run"
2. Type `netplwiz` and click "OK"
3. Uncheck "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer."

Comment: Thanks! Idea why this was a problem?

Comment: @DavidB The default is to ask for a password. That's all there is to it.  Previous versions of Windows would just automatically "uncheck" the checkbox when there was only one user account and it had no password, but Windows 10 *wants* to show you the lockscreen, either for security (so other people think you have a password) or for usability (because you can have status icons show up there for various apps).

Comment: The strange thing is that I have been running Windows 10 on my machine for several days now and this only started happening today.

Comment: Windows update recently? (Maybe one of the updates triggers that)

Comment: wow, so intuitive Microsoft, netplwiz.

Comment: @dancarter there are other more intuitive ways to get to the same place. Typing this just happens to be the quickest one.

Comment: As of 2023, the above method did not work for me on Windows 10.  Specifically, the relevant checkbox no longer appears in `netplwiz`. (This despite trying various tricks to make the checkbox "reappear").  However, I was able to achieve automatic login by creating three registry keys (`DefaultUserName`, `DefaultPassword`, and `AutoAdminLogon`) in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` as described at [helpdeskgeek.com](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-set-up-windows-10-to-login-automatically/).

Comment: @mpb You should post that as an answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

Moshe Katz requested that I repost my above comment as a separate answer.

As of 2023, the only method I found that works to automatically log in to Windows 10 is the following:

Use `regedit` to create and/or edit the following registry keys in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`:

Create and or edit the following keys:

- Set `DefaultUserName` to the user name.
- Set `DefaultPassword` to the user's password.
- Set `AutoAdminLogon` to the string `1`.

Source:
https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-set-up-windows-10-to-login-automatically/