# Suddenly Windows 10 asked for Password

Tags: windows, windows-10

This morning I got a call from my friend. I built his computer. In the past, he used a local account without password. That is the thing he asked for and he likes to use the computer in this way. But This morning, suddenly, Windows 10 went to the login screen and asked him to set a password unless it won't allow him to login. I am worried that this is caused by a virus. Has anyone seen this happen before? Thanks!

Comment: Its possible he converted his local account into a windows live account. This is done for example when someone wants to download something from the windows app store.

Comment: [similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/947281/windows-10-asks-me-to-enter-a-password)

Comment: Has he just tried leaving the password blank?

Comment: Or maybe he has attached his computer to the domain, that may be the cause.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that the password is expired, and Windows forces your friend to change password. Just follow the logon screen to set a new password. Once logged in, you can turn off password expiration policy:

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key + <kbd>R</kbd> to open Run. Type **lusrmgr.msc** and press
   Enter.
2. Click **Users** in the left pane, then double-click on your desired user
       in the right pane.
3. When the account properties dialog box opens, check the "**Password
       never expires**" option and click **OK**.