# Cannot remove local user password Windows 11

Tags: security, passwords, user-accounts, windows-11

I am using Windows 11 with a local account which is also an admin. What I want to do is to remove the password from this account so that I log in automatically.

When I run `lusrmgr.msc` and change the password, I get this error:

[image]

[image]

Translation of the error:

```
Error while trying to set password
The password does not meet the requirements of the Password Policy. Check the minimum password length, password complexity, and password history requirements.
```

### What I did before

running `netplwiz`, I removed the following option:

```
users must enter a user name and password to use this computer
```

[image]

I also don't see any obstcle in `gpedit.msc` (group policy) settings:

[image]

Comment: If you want it to auto-login, why not just set it to do that. Admin accounts without passwords are a bad idea, & not just for the obvious reasons. It will prevent you authorising many structures. Give it a good password, set it to auto-login. It's right there in netplwiz.

Comment: where is the autologin option in netplwiz? I updated the screenshot in the question

Comment: See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html [it's been a long time since I actually did it myself, so I can't really help further]

Comment: All you need to do is enable “users must enter a user name and password to use this computer” then immediately disable it with your username selected, and when prompted for the password, enter the password your current password [here](https://superuser.com/questions/495015/how-to-enable-automatic-login-in-windows-8/495020#495020) are some instructions on that process. Even if your password was blank, you would have to enter your password, without performing those steps.  Setting the default username is the only way to have your machine automatically login to your desired username

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 Asks me to Enter a Password](https://superuser.com/questions/947281/windows-10-asks-me-to-enter-a-password). This duplicate is absolutely applicable to Windows 11

Comment: yes, exactly. all i need was to use netplwiz and disable “users must enter a user name and password to use this computer” as you mentioned. My mistake was leaving blank the password. however using my current password, I don't need to use password on each login.