# Autologin on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, auto-login

How to setup autologin when system starts on Windows 11. I was trying to find this option in Settings>>Accounts, but found nothing related to that.

[image]

I was trying to follow other method:

1. Right-click the Windows Logo (Start Button) and click "Run"
2. Type netplwiz and click "OK"
3. Uncheck "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer."

But there is no option `"Users must enter a username and password to use this computer."`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 Asks me to Enter a Password](https://superuser.com/questions/947281/windows-10-asks-me-to-enter-a-password).  The duplicate question's answer is still applicable to Windows 11 21H2.  The option to set a default user does not reside in Settings.

Comment: Is this macine connected to an AD domain by chance?

Comment: You need to disable `Require Windows Hello sign-in for Microsoft accounts.` and `Make your device passwordless` for the option to appear.  I still say this is a duplicate, once those options are disabled, since it will allow you to set a default user and automatically log into that user profile.

Comment: @harrymc - The author still has to enable those two options before your answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramhound says first step is to disable the pesky *Windows Hello Sign-in*
launch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> paste `ms-settings:signinoptions`

Disable it
[ms-settings:signinoptions window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Vtm.jpg)

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> paste `netplwiz`

Untick *"Users must enter..."*
[netplwiz window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNF0r.jpg)

After all of this Windows 11 were still asking me for a login! And I didn't want to store my password in plain text in registry as @harrymc answer requires.

Then I found that little program from Microsoft that finally gets the job done: [AutoLogon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon)

Download, store it somewhere, enter your credentials and Voila!

Comment: Something must have changed. Those options do not exist on my windows 11 version. The dialogs look different. All the webtutorials i’ve found are not applicable (anymore). I deleted the password for the main user and that seemed to have worked.